# In OpenMDAO, why might removing a 'loose' constraint makes check_totals give 'incorrect' answers

Tags: derivative, openmdao

I have a model with 11 design variables and 9 constraints. I've run check_partials and I'm satisfied that the analytic derivatives are correct. When I run check_totals (or run the `openmdao scaling` script), I see that certain rows of the Jacobian have anomalously large values (of order 10^13) and don't agree with the finite-difference results (which are of order 1).

I can 'fix' this by either removing a design variable or adding a new constraint, even if the constraint is extremely 'loose' such that it can never approach the bound. Then the finite difference and analytic derivatives agree (and are order 1).
It doesn't seem to matter which of the design variables I drop; when I have 10 design variables and 9 constraints, the result is the same.
Likewise, it doesn't seem to matter which output variable I add a constraint to; when I have 11 design variables and 10 constraints, the result is the same.

I don't think this is a result of the specific driver: I've tried this with both `pyOptSparseDriver` and `IPOPT` and the `ScipyOptimizeDriver` with `SLSQP`, and the behavior is the same.

While I'm not certain that this behavior is a limiting factor to me at the moment, it certainly seems odd and potentially harmful.
Does this point to a bug, behavior that can be fixed with the right settings, or a simple consequence of linear algebra?

Comment: are you saying that when you add a new DV or a new constraint that there is an effect on a different row or column?

Comment: Yes. That seems contrary to how I would expect total derivatives to work.

Comment: @JustinGray specifically on a different row, as presented in the `openmdao scaling` viewer.

Comment: that is very very strange, but I don't have enough information to give you a real answer. Could you either post a code snippet or the N2 maybe?

Comment: Thanks for the vote of 'strange', I'm glad to know it's not normal. Right now I'm seeing this in a large (for me) model but I can try to reduce it down to a MWE, or see what I fix along the way. Not immediately though.